# Create VCards with iPhone Address Book Contacts

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, frameworks, addressbook

I am wondering if there is some way to create and send VCards based upon the iPhone Address Book information from my own app.  On the Mac, there is some easy function in the built in app to do this, but I have not seen something on the iPhone like this.  So, is there some framework or otherwise that enables me to turn contacts on the iPhone into VCards?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a "share contact" button at the bottom of every contact in the contacts app on the phone, press it and you can email a VCard to whoever you want.

Comment: Hi Carl: Thanks!  I didn't notice that.  Is there some way to replicate this experience in my app?

Comment: That I have no idea about, sorry.