# Looking for a library for vCard generation and parsing in Objective-C, C, C++ (for iPhone)

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, cocoa, vcf-vcard

I would like to be able to parse a vCard from a string and produce a string representation for a vCard.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard It seems to be pretty simple... You could make an array for each line, then make a dictionary separated by a colon for each object in the array. For the parsing, at least.

Comment: https://github.com/aussiegeek/AddressBookVcardImport/blob/master/Classes/VcardImporter.m Actually looks pretty good. Butcher this guy's code and you should be rolling.

Comment: Aurum: Why not post that comment as an answer?

Comment: you don't need to any library any more see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2996334/1671176

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [library](http://altoshstock.blogspot.com/2010/11/iphone-os-generate-vcard.html), I'm not the creator but i've used and it works just fine. Just take a look in the comments as there is a error that needs fixing in the library.