# Using initWithVCardRepresentation

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook, vcf-vcard

So I have used an instance of ABRecordRef to create an ABPerson using "ABPersonCreate()".

What I would now like to be able to do is use the "initWithVCardRepresentation" to add preset details to the ABPerson created.

I have no idea how to do this and my searches seem to keep coming up dry so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of
[Generate vCard from AddressBook.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795615/generate-vcard-from-addressbook-framework)
and
[Looking for a library for vCard generation and parsing in Objective-C, C, C++ (for iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208581/looking-for-a-library-for-vcard-generation-and-parsing-in-objective-c-c-c-fo)

which both end up suggesting you should implement your own (perhaps based on some ready made internet code, found in those links)

Cheers,

Oded.