# How to create vCard from address book using ios sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

I do not know how to create vCard from Address book. I can generate NSString for vCard data by searching but I dont know how to convert NSString to .vcf. Here is my code for NSString of vCard data.

```
NSString *vcard = @"BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n";

    // Name
    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"N:%@;%@;%@;%@;%@\n",
             (contact.lastname ? contact.lastname : @""),
             (contact.firstname ? contact.firstname : @""),
             (contact.middlename ? contact.middlename : @""),
             (contact.prefix ? contact.prefix : @""),
             (contact.suffix ? contact.suffix : @"")
             ];

    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"FN:%@\n",contact.compositeName];
    if(  contact.nickname ) vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"NICKNAME:%@\n",contact.nickname];
    if(  contact.firstnamephonetic ) vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"X-PHONETIC-FIRST-NAME:%@\n",contact.firstnamephonetic];
    if(  contact.lastnamephonetic ) vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"X-PHONETIC-LAST-NAME:%@\n",contact.lastnamephonetic];


    // Work
    if( contact.organization || contact.department ) vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"ORG:%@;%@\n",(contact.organization?contact.organization:@""),(contact.department?contact.department:@"")];
    if( contact.jobtitle ) vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"TITLE:%@\n",contact.jobtitle];


    // Mail
    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingString:[VCard toVcardField:@"email" items:contact.emailArray labels:contact.emailLabels]];

    // Tel
    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingString:[VCard toVcardField:@"phone" items:contact.phoneArray labels:contact.phoneLabels]];

    // Adress
    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingString:[VCard toVcardField:@"address" items:contact.addressArray labels:contact.addressLabels]];

    // url
    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingString:[VCard toVcardField:@"url" items:contact.urlArray labels:contact.urlLabels]];

    // IM
    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingString:[VCard toVcardField:@"im" items:contact.smsArray labels:contact.smsLabels]];

    // birthday
    NSDate *birthday = contact.birthday;
    if (birthday)
    {
        NSString *bday = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",birthday];
        NSArray *bdayArr = [bday componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        bday = [bdayArr objectAtIndex:0];

        vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"BDAY;value=date:%@\n",bday];
    }

    // Photo
    NSData *imageData = contact.thumbData;//contact.imageData;
    if (imageData)
    {
        //vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingFormat:@"PHOTO;BASE64:%@\n",[imageData base64Encoding]];
    }

    // end
    vcard = [vcard stringByAppendingString:@"END:VCARD"];
```

and I get NSSTring as an output :

```
vCard : BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:def;Abc;;;
FN:Abc def
ORG:slk;
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=HOME:fdf@gmail.com
TEL;type=CELL:(258) 963-4889
TEL;type=IPHONE:(435) 768-6343
item1.ADR;type=HOME:;;aashram road;Ahmedabad;;;India
item1.X-ABADR:in
END:VCARD
```

Can anybody help me to convert this NSString to .vcf file to get vCard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795615/generate-vcard-from-addressbook-framework

Comment: Hello, Thanks for asking question because I am working on same thing but can you help me how can I export this .vcf to particular email and how can I attach this .vcf file to email Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can u pls tell me that what is `[VCard toVcardField:@"email" items:contact.emailArray labels:contact.emailLabels]` is this any default method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory

NSError *error;
BOOL succeed = [yourNSString writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contact.vcf"]
                          atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!succeed){
    // Handle error here
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

This code save the vcard on Documents directory of your app.

yourNSString is the variable you use when you generate the vcard

Comment: can you pls suggest me abt my above comment. or pls give complete details to create vcard

Comment: i use this method but i'm getting MIME/content-type = "text/directory" i need "text/x-vcard". Plzz help