# How to create vcf file programmatically ?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to select multiple contacts from address book and saving to my App. Now If I delete any of the contact from Address Book & it is the one previously saved in my app,In order to restore deleted contact i need to create vcf file.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795615/generate-vcard-from-addressbook-framework

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing for iOS 5.0 or later then use following methods:

> **CFArrayRef ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation (
>      ABRecordRef source,
>      CFDataRef vCardData
>   )**
>
> CFArrayRef ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople (
>      CFArrayRef people
>   )

And documentation is here :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html

> **Note:-** Reading documentation carefully will help you a lot to develop entire project.